# Is there any way to keep on adding extra column that is coming in a file to "other" column in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario where my file schema might change.For example: consider if i am getting 3 columns `"A","B","C"` now ; next time I might get a case when 2 new columns are added in the file `"A","B","C","D","E"`. 
In that case, I want to add it to the `"other"` column (of  JSON type) in the dataframe something like

```
A  B  C  others
------------
1  2  3  {"D":4,"E":5}
```

Also there can be a case when a column might be missing, for example, I might not be getting column A and will be getting "B", "C" only.
How to handle this in pyspark ?

Comment: Before downvoting the question please take some time to read it properly. Everything is explained already. Don't be super rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****You can use something like following -****

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.csv("demo.csv", header=True)
df_1 = df.select([c for c in df.columns if c not in {'A', 'B', 'C'}]) # this will give your unknown columns
df.select("A","B", "C", to_json(struct(df_1.columns)).alias("other")).show(10,False)
```

**Note**: demo.csv has these columns `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']` - this list can vary, and out of which `['A', 'B', 'C']` are your fixed/known columns.

Comment: Thank you .I tried this, And it is working.